# Invoke webrtc-internals dump programmatically

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Is it possible to invoke chrome://webrtc-internals dump programmatically from JavaScript?
I know its just peerconnection stats but the goal is to dump them in the same format so that tools like testRTC or [this one](https://github.com/fippo/webrtc-dump-importer) can be used based on a dump provided by a user (which they retrieve from the app).

Comment: On testRTC, we actually have the watchRTC SDK which collects that automatically from all your users: https://testrtc.com/watchrtc/

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible. https://github.com/jitsi/rtcstats is a maintained fork of my rtcstats library which provides similar functionality.